# updating specific row value with some condition MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i have a table with id,jml_tetangga,tetangga1,tetangga 2 as column

```
id jml_tetangga tetangga1 tetangga2
1  0            6         7
2  0            3         NULL
3  0            2         6
5  0            NULL      NULL
```

i need help to update jml_tetangga **for each row** based on wether tetangga1 and/or tetangga2 is null or not, if tetangga1 value is not null then jml_tetangga value will be +1, if both tetangga1 and tetangga2 is not null then jml_tetangga will be +2

the result would look like this (in this case there's no id 4 because row with id 4 has been deleted)

```
id jml_tetangga tetangga1 tetangga2
1  2            6         7
2  1            3         NULL
3  2            2         6
5  0            NULL      NULL
```

i already tried this

```
update dosen_matkul 
set jumlah_tetangga = 
case when (select tetangga1 from dosen_matkul where id=1) IS NULL THEN 1 
else 0 END,
jumlah_tetangga = 
case when (select tetangga2 from dosen_matkul where id=1) IS NULL THEN 2 
else 0 END where id =1
```

but i got error 1093, whats the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is close, but the syntax is bit off.  Try this version:

```
UPDATE dosen_matkul 
SET jml_tetangga = CASE WHEN tetangga1 IS NOT NULL AND tetangga2 IS NOT NULL
                        THEN jml_tetangga + 2
                        WHEN tetangga1 IS NOT NULL
                        THEN jml_tetangga + 1
                        ELSE jml_tetangga END;
```

[image]

Here is demo showing that the update logic being used is correct:

### Demo